# Change Detection and Events from outside of Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have created and Angular 7 Application that uses a very large external library. I have all thing wired up with success with the exception of an event from that external sources.

I have an event listener on that external sources that fires and sends data to my Angular App.

```
externalApp.event((data)=>{
  this.externalMonitorService.newData(external.data)
});
```

That works fine.

This function then uses a BehaviorSubject and emits the data

```
newData(data){
  this.mySubject.next(data);
}
```

That is working fine as well.

I can subscribe to this in any component and I get changes, it works fine.

However, in my template I can not use async pipe as it does not detect the changes. I have to `ChangeDetectorRef` and update a variable and then call detectChanges.

I don't want to have to worry about this subscription, to have to implement this logic in every component, it is very ummmm... *reactive breaking*.

Am I missing something deep in Angular I do not know about? Is there a way in angular, perhaps NgZone where I can call something that lets Angular know, this data is coming from an external source treat this as a change, thus I will not have to implement this logic everywhere.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what this external library does and why it's external to your application?

Comment: By the way, did you specified any `changeDetectionStrategy` in that component?

Comment: could you also tell use more about your BehaviorSubject ? Have notice than if you init your behaviorSubject by null, that hijack the changeDetection from async pipe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you should inject ngZone and wrap the call into its `run` method.

```
this.ngZone.run(() => this.externalMonitorService.newData(external.data));
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, I guess it is time for me to accept I must dive into ngzone, I have shamefully avoided it.